# Prestashop: show condition in product list

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I want to show the condition (new, refurbished etc.) in the product listing.

I tried to use the code from the product page, but somehow it doesn't show anything in the product list.

In product-list.tpl I added the following code right after the price-code (begin is original code):

```
<div class="content_price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
{if isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
<span itemprop="price" class="price product-price">
{if !$priceDisplay}{convertPrice price=$product.price}{else}{convertPrice
price=$product.price_tax_exc}{/if}

<!-- added code for condition -->
{if $product->condition}
        <p id="product_condition">
            <label>{l s='Condition'} </label>
            {if $product->condition == 'new'}
                <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition"/>
                <span class="editable">{l s='New'}</span>
            {elseif $product->condition == 'used'}
                <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/UsedCondition"/>
                <span class="editable">{l s='Used'}</span>
            {elseif $product->condition == 'refurbished'}
                <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/RefurbishedCondition"/>
                <span class="editable">{l s='Refurbished'}</span>
            {/if}
        </p>
        {/if}
</span>
```

So nothing happens in this case. If I replace the code with normal text it does show, so it looks like "condition" can not be shown here?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. In product page `$product` is an object, but in product list it is an array.

Instead of `$product->condition` use `$product.condition`.